# One username for all databases or multiple MySQL accounts?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, database-design

Say I have a PHP web application like a CMS or something, and each new user has their own hosting area on a server - should they all have their own mySQL username and password and a database for their site data tied to their account, or rather one mySQL user/pass that the web app uses to connect with for all users with a database on that account?

Is there any performance issues with this if you gain a lot of users (60-100+)?

Eg, for example a database structure like this:

```
(prefix) host_
              userDB1
              userDB2
              userDB3
              ...
etc.
```

And one mysql account that each application uses to connect to their respective database and pull data from their tables?

Or should each user db (which could have a good number of tables in) be under their own host area with a separate mysql account for each?

I hope this makes sense. I've been looking around and reading a lot to try and find the best way to structure databases that will need to handle a lot of users eventually.

Comment: Are these users qualified to be poking around in a db?

Comment: Do the users actually access the database themselves directly, or is their only view to the data provided via the application?

Comment: Why would 1 user want to connect to all databases? security reasons, it's best to provide 1 user all access to 1 database.. whether the user has access to the mysql login or through the scripts.

Comment: @MikeBrant All via the web app, none have direct access.

Comment: @DarylGill The mysql user just has enough privs to do what the app requires (ie. update, insert etc) No major admin stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your statement that all DB access is through the app, I don't see why you would want to have separate users for each client, as ultimately your application will need to be built to handle user permissions anyway.

Now whether or not you choose to use separate databases is really a design decision you need to make, and would likely hinge around how much separation of data you need in the application, application data management processes (i.e. performing DB backups), whether you need custom schema for each user, whether you need to be able to easily aggregate data across users, etc.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and initially that was why I thought of doing it this way. I just wanted to make sure that it wouldn't hinder performance on load times etc from the database if it all comes from one user or something, compared to separate users. But if it is purely just a case of a design decision, then that's fine.

Comment: @MrLewk If anything having multiple usernames may be more problematic for you in a high concurrency situation as this might cause you to hold open more connections to the DB than you would otherwise need to with a single user account.

Comment: Alright thanks that helps. So in terms of security as others have mentioned, what are the best methods? At the moment, the user just has basic privs to updates, insert etc that the app requires. Is there more that can be done?

Comment: @MrLewk In regards to security you just need to keep the basics in mind.  Ideally you have your app's MySQL login credential outside of your web root.  If you have the MySQL daemon running on the same server as the web application then you should prevent any logins from outside the server.  This can be done at the server level by making setting the bind-address in my.ini to 127.0.0.1. If on a separate machine, you can either set bind address specifically to the IP of your application server, or set to 0.0.0.0 the root an app user accounts only have access from proper IP's.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. You see, if we think about linux we get the answer to your "management" question.

For example, to each service you may have a different user on a linux server, so if one user get's compromissed, only one service will as well. You can simply worry about one problem instead of multiple problems.

I also built a CRM and had this doubt years ago. I use one username and password to each database and (just to make sure it's really safe), each database has a user that it's allow to make changes and another one only to use "select" statements.

I did this way also because I like to check user's that are using mysql, sometimes is usefull to know where's the request's comming from and keep an eye on it.

Your CRM have a installer, right? You can easily create the database, the user and add to the database. So it's easy and won't take your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer an account for each hoisting. And restrict the write permission of a user only to his DB.

Comment: But does either way give any performance issues/benefits? What I mean is, would their websites or whatever, load faster if it was just their account with their database, rather than everyone's database under one account?

Comment: there is not performance diff here. its about more secure data.